# Проброс PCI устройства в Virtualbox 4.2

Tags: debian, virtualbox

Насколько знаю, вроде можно пробросить pci уст-во гостевой оси. Но ни в каких настройках эта фича не светится. Подскажите, кто знает, как?

(Гостевая и хостовая ос - дебиан).

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [здесь](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#pcipassthrough)